# Can a thread be created and joined by different threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

if A creates thread B and C with `pthread_create`, can B call `pthread_join` on C (assuming the thread_id `pthread_t` of C is accessible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no parent-child relationship between POSIX threads. All threads are peers. Any thread can be joined by any other.